Hard code block with nested block in front-page.html template
I have two working blocks hero Carousel and hero Carousel Slide. When I hard code these blocks in the template file they do not appear nested in the editor. In the editor, I am able to drag and drop the child block into the parent block as well as use the + icon to add the child block into the parent. How does one invoke blocks with nested blocks in a template file, when creating a bespoke theme.
in front-page.html
<!-- wp:mytheme/herocarousel /-->
  <!-- wp:mytheme/herocarouselslide /-->
<!-- /wp:mytheme/herocarousel /-->


If you insert things the way you want in the editor and then copy and paste them you'll get the correct output.
The mistake you've made here is the / closing the block comment:
<!-- wp:mytheme/herocarousel /-->

Should be:
<!-- wp:mytheme/herocarousel -->

Only use /--> if the block has no content or children.
